# Trigger to ensure each new bid is higher than previous

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with my trigger in SQL Server.

This trigger checks if the new bidding is higher then the existing ones and if not raise an error:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_bod_validate_Bodbedrag] 
ON [dbo].[bod] 
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
DECLARE @v_Voorwerp numeric(25);
DECLARE @v_Bodbedrag char(6);
DECLARE @v_Max_Bodbedrag char(6);

select @v_Voorwerp = i.voorwerp, @v_Bodbedrag = i.bodbedrag
from Inserted i;

SELECT @v_Max_Bodbedrag = max(CAST(bodbedrag AS INT))
FROM bod
WHERE voorwerp = @v_Voorwerp;

IF @v_Max_Bodbedrag <=   @v_Bodbedrag 
BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('Bod moet hoger zijn dan gegeven bod.', 16, 1)
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END;
ELSE
    PRINT 'Row Inserted';
```

Now I get this error Bid amount is less then maximum, that is not acceptable', even when I insert a bidding when there aren't any existing bids.

What could be the problem?

*For your knowledge: Voorwerp: Product, Bodbedrag: Amount of bid*

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  If you are using SQL Server, your trigger is just fundamentally broken, because it assumes that `inserted` has only one row.  You need to fix the trigger, removing this assumption.

Comment: So i have to make it compatible with sql server

Comment: The other assumption is that there will be a max bodbedrag that you'll find. It's possible that the table is empty and there's no/null max bodbedrag.

Comment: THINK! Why is Bodbedrag variable defined as char(6)? "Amount of bid" certainly sounds like a numeric value. Your code obviously assumes it is and casts it to int. Are your bids only whole numbers?

Comment: bodbedrag defined as char.

Comment: This is the error i get:`Row Inserted
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trg_bod_validate_Bodbedrag, Line 14 [Batch Start Line 9]
Bod moet hoger zijn dan gegeven bod.
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.`

Comment: @crazybob . . . Your code is broken.  I would suggest that you ask a new question with sample data, desired results, scenarios you need to handle, a clear explanation of the logic, and you can include your attempt if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Points to note:

1. In SQL Server the [Inserted (and Deleted) pseudo-tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) can have from 0-N rows where N is the number of rows being inserted/updated/deleted. And this has to be handled in any trigger. However as soon as you switch into set-based thinking (instead of procedural) you find its a much simpler problem anyway.
2. Of course we can't (easily) discriminate between rows which are OK and those which aren't, we basically have to reject the entire insert/update even if its just one row which breaks the rules.
3. So the join finds the `max(bodbedrag)` for *all* products which exist in `Inserted` - excluding the row which is being inserted/updated - because as far as we are concerned the insert/update has already taken place and that data exists in our database - until we rollback if we choose to.
4. I've ignored your use of a `char` instead of a `decimal`. Ideally you would correct your datatypes, but you can continue to cast/convert if you wish. I'll leave that to you.
5. Note we use `throw` these days, not `raiserror`.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_bod_validate_Bodbedrag] 
ON [dbo].[bod] 
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Find the max of for inserted voorwerp's excluding the currently inserted/updated
    -- Is an update of existing bid even allowed
    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Inserted I
        LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT MAX(bodbedrag) bodbedrag
          FROM dbo.dob D
          INNER JOIN Inserted I ON I.voorwerp = D.voorwerp and I.ID <> D.ID
        ) D
        WHERE I.bodbedrag < coalesce(D.bodbedrag,0)
    ) BEGIN
        -- THROW should be used now, not RAISERROR
        -- RAISERROR ('Bod moet hoger zijn dan gegeven bod.', 16, 1);
        THROW 51000, 'Bod moet hoger zijn dan gegeven bod.', 1;  
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END; ELSE BEGIN
        PRINT 'Row Inserted';
    END;
END
```